# Logic for simple switch case in React

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement

I need to change the component that is shown depending on flag value. 0 is equal to null, but 1 and 2 will generate the same component but with a different custom message.

I've tried piecing together a switch, but I'm not getting any console output.

```
switch (flagValue) {
            case 1: 
                console.log('1')
                break;
            case 2:
                console.log('2 or 5')
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

I may be way off base here^^

This is the code that I am attempting the switch case for. The `<AlertBox>` component content will change depending on `case:1` or `case:2`

```
if (flagValue !== 0) {
            return null;
        } else
            return (
                <AlertBox
                    title={`Your ${
                        this.props.Year
                    } Payment Has Not Been Processed`}
                    content={
                        <span>
                            custom text here
                            <b>
                                {` ${this.props.month}`} 15,{' '}
                                {`${this.props.currentYear}`}{' '}
                            </b>
                        </span>
                    }
                    headerLevel={2}
                />
            );
```

Comment: You may find this react library: npmjs.com/package/react-floco useful if you need to render by switch/case statements in future

Answer (score 0):

if you only explicitly want the values 1 and 2 then you can use simple conditional rendering. Note that this probably becomes quite ugly once you add more cases.

```
return (
    <AlertBox
        title={`Your ${
            this.props.Year
            } Payment Has Not Been Processed`}
        content={
            <span>
                {flagValue === 1 && 'Custom Message 1'}
                {flagValue === 2 && 'Custom Message 2'}
                <b>
                    {` ${this.props.month}`} 15,{' '}
                    {`${this.props.currentYear}`}{' '}
                </b>
            </span>
        }
        headerLevel={2}
    />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that flagValue is a number instead of a string? Switch statements use strict equality `===`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch